# tkinter и завершение приложения системой

Tags: python, tkinter, nuitka

Хочу отловить корректное завершение работы системы, во время работы программы отдельным каждые 15 сек пишется временный файл, по событию завершения файл убирается, в лог пишется время события, и дальше нормальное завершение. На PyQt5 всё прекрасно, перевёл приложение на tkinter, при РУЧНОМ закрытии программы всё прекрасно, НО ПРИ ЗАВЕРШЕНИИ РАБОТЫ Windows (XP x86) ветка closeEvent не выполняется. 
Приложение собрано в *.exe с помощью nuitka.

Вот код:

```
netPing.py:

from ui.netPing import MainWindow
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ui = MainWindow()
```

ui/netPing.py

```
import os, threading
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

class MainWindow():
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        ...
        self.t1 = threading.Thread(target = self.watchdog, args = ())
        self.t1.daemon = True
        self.t1.start()
        ...
        root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.closeEvent)
        root.mainloop()

    def watchdog(self):
        while self.watchdogEnabled:
            tmpfile = open('tmp', 'w')
            tmpfile.write(datetime.now().strftime('%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S'))
            tmpfile.close()
            ...
            except: pass
            sleep(15)

    def closeEvent(self):
        self.watchdogEnabled = False
        try: os.remove('tmp')
        except: pass
        self.logWrite('Shutdown', 1)
        ...
        root.destroy()
```

на PyQt5:
    в ui/netPing.py:

```
@pyqtSlot()
def closeEvent(self, event):
    self.watchdogEnabled = False
    try: os.remove('tmp')
    except: pass
    self.logWrite('Shutdown', 1)
    ...
    event.accept()
```

Comment: создайте *минимальный*, но полный пример кода, который проблему показывает (как бонус покажите *минимальный* pyqt5 код, который "работает"). Вызываются ли [atexit обработчики](https://docs.python.org/3/library/atexit.html#atexit-example) у вас? Явно  опишите какая у вас система, как вы её завершаете. Перечислите версии используемого ПО. [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашёл ответ тут:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/24028368/8188959

```
import signal

def in_close(signum = None, frame = None):
    # Here you can attempt to gently exit your application.
    pass

# For some common signals that will close your program.
for sig in [signal.SIGTERM, signal.SIGINT, signal.SIGHUP, signal.SIGQUIT]:
    signal.signal(sig, in_close)
```

Answer (score 1):

не знаю `+-` воспроизвел ваш код и для примера вот рабочий вариант (если вам конечно вот подобное надо)

P.s. не знаю зачем вам заморозка программы на 15сек если ее можно реализовать благополучно `root.after(15000, func)`

Сам код:

```
import tkinter as tk
import os
import random
import string


class Main(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.close_event)
        self.anytime = "".join([random.choice(string.ascii_letters) for _ in range(4)]) + ".txt"
        self.watchdog()

    def watchdog(self):
        tmpfile = open(self.anytime, 'w')
        tmpfile.write(str(random.randint(1, 1000)))
        tmpfile.close()
        self.after(15000, self.watchdog)

    def close_event(self):
        try:
            os.remove(self.anytime)
        except FileNotFoundError:
            pass
        with open("config.txt", "w") as text:
            text.write(self.anytime)
        self.destroy()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Main().mainloop()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо, но о том и речь, что при ручном закрытии всё выполняется корректно, но при выключении компьютера, когда СИСТЕМА завершает процессы, эта ветка кода не выполянется.  А фриза нет, я не указал, но watchdog выполянется в отдельном потоке (threading).